# Explode or cut string based on specific digit

Tags: javascript

I have this integer on javascript. I want to trim or explode it after seeing a digit > 0 after number 0. For example:

```
var digit = 8001000
```

The result should be `digit[0] = 800` and `digit[1] = 1000`.

It should find a number more than 0 after the last zero number then cuts it. It should only cut zeroes from the middle and not including the zeroes found near the end of the digit.

Another example to be more clear

```
var digit = 80100
```

The result should be `digit[0] = 80` and `digit[1] = 100`. So it doesn't matter how many zeroes as long as those results are met.

Any answers will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't really split a number, but you can turn it into a string, use match to match any number with trailing zeros, then map the values back to numbers

```
digit.toString().match(/[1-9]+0+/g).map(Number);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7sos4p4m/1/)

Comment: If that is a homework problem, the OP just failed -- the code is too slick and professional to be student work.

Comment: Should be /[1-9]+0*/g in order to match 8010032.  Assuming the answer is [80, 100, 32]

Comment: a little explanation if possible what you wrote, what it means and how it works

Comment: It turns the number to a string, then uses regex with a global match to get a split array of the string, then it uses map to convert all array objects from String to Number.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad - `split` accepts a regular expression, this one matches any number between 1 and 9, the `+` basically means there can be more than one such number, the number must then be followed by one or more zeros. The map at the end turns the array back into numbers.

Comment: @DMoses - true, but that's not in the question. The posted answer should work, otherwise your comment provides a solution if it's needed, thanks !

Comment: Thanks! You're a real lifesaver!

Comment: @EhsanSajjad https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions That is where you want to go.  Msg me if you have specific questions.

Answer (score 1):

```
var num = 8001000;
(''+num).match(/([^0]+0+)/g);
// returns ["800", "1000"]
```

Cast the number to a string, then find all the occurrences of NOT-ZERO followed by ZEROES.

Answer (score 0):

not tested, but that's one for [regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/t0kbytzc%28v=vs.94%29.aspx):

```
 digit1 = digit.replace(/([0-9]*0)[1-9][0-9]*$/, "$1");
 digit2 = digit.replace(/[0-9]*0([1-9][0-9]*)$/, "$1");
```